# Create a column for Month from a column of date (however the date column does not contain the month information)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like this, and want to create a column called 'Month'

```
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Name    | Task             | Team | Date |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 1    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| John    | Accounting       | B    | 2    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Michael | Customer service | A    | 2    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Joanna  | Market study     | C    | 2    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| John    | Customer service | C    | 1    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Michael | Market study     | A    | 1    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Joanna  | Customer service | B    | 1    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 2    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 2    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 2    |
+---------+------------------+------+------+
```

So basicly, I have the date information, but the date does not contain the month it belongs to. However, I know that if it occurs the first time, then it will belong the Month 1, if it occurs for the second time, then it will belong to Month 2. So for example, date 1 occurs 3 time, then interrupted by date 2. So the first 3 time belongs to month 1, and the next 3 times occur, it belong to Month 2. So I would like my result like this:

```
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Name    | Task             | Team | Date | Month   |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Market study     | C    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Customer service | C    | 1    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 2    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 2    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 2    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
```

I do not have any idea, other than just using some loops.
Thank you all.

Comment: If *what* occurs the first time? I can't find a pattern, sorry.

Comment: if the date occurs the first time (in the date column, you see date 1, 2. But date 1 occurs 3 times, then interrupted by date 2, then date 1 appears again, then date 2 appears again. This means that the first time date 1 occurs, it belongs to month 1, the second time it occurs, it belongs to month 2

Comment: Sorry I still don't find it clear enough, when date AND Name repeats, then month should be 2?

Comment: For example, date 1 occurs 3 times, then it is interrupted by date 2, also occur 3 times. It means that date 1 belongs to month 1 in the first 3 occurances, the next time it appears, it belongs to month 2. I really do not know how to say clearer, English is not my first language, and it is not an easy question to ask.

Comment: Depending on how many outcomes you have, I suggest looking at pd.where (or .np)  and np.select

Comment: yes, thank you, I will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you may do following: create mask `s` to separate each consective values into separate group. From `s`, create mask `s1` to each value of each group. Groupby `s1` and `Date` and doing `cumcount` and `map` to create desired output:

```
s = df.Date.ne(df.Date.shift()).cumsum()
s1 = df.Date.groupby(s).cumcount()

df['Month'] = df.groupby([s1, 'Date']).Name.cumcount().add(1).map(lambda x: 'Month '+str(x))

Out[897]:
       Name              Task Team  Date    Month
0      John      Market-study    A     1  Month 1
1   Michael  Customer-service    B     1  Month 1
2    Joanna        Accounting    C     1  Month 1
3      John        Accounting    B     2  Month 1
4   Michael  Customer-service    A     2  Month 1
5    Joanna      Market-study    C     2  Month 1
6      John  Customer-service    C     1  Month 2
7   Michael      Market-study    A     1  Month 2
8    Joanna  Customer-service    B     1  Month 2
9      John      Market-study    A     2  Month 2
10  Michael  Customer-service    B     2  Month 2
11   Joanna        Accounting    C     2  Month 2
```

Comment: `df.Date` is equivalent to `df['Date']`